Boot problem after installing NVidia drivers
I've been using Ubuntu for the past few years and have generally doing well. Recently I invited my friend to switch over his development environment to Ubuntu. We successfully installed Ubuntu 22.04 on hus Asus FX507 and to make sure we were able to dual boot into both Windows and Ubuntu. When I install nvidia 535-tested and reboot I face this problem gaveup waiting for root file system, UUID does not exist. When I boot into a live session I clearly see that this UUID does exist and its my root.
Do I have to retry with another driver version? Point that laptop has some sotrage feature named Intel VMD or something like it that I hadn't heard of before.
I reinstalled Ubuntu 2 times and this happend again.
